# training CNN cpu in 100% but failed

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a CNN model to recognize MNIST datasets, when i run this code, my IDE became unresponsive, i review many times but can't find where is wrong.Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


def weight(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

W_conv1 = weight([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias([32])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight([7*7*64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias([10])

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, 1), tf.argmax(y_conv, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(20000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval({x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run({x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

i can't copy the running information, my cpu worked 100%. 
it can just print "step 100, 0.12",and then no thing happened.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `if i % 100` check? Maybe your CPU needs some time to get from i = 0 (where the if-statement evaluates to true the first time) to i = 100 (where the if-statement evaluates to true the second time).

Comment: thx, but not works. no responsive again, and i have to cut off electric source to  make it stop.

Comment: Maybe try to set a breakpoint before the train call and go step by step through the training function to see where it hangs.

Comment: What happens if you just run the python code without you IDE?